# virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks

Tags: python, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to install `virtualenvwrapper`. I need to use specific python version: `3.6.10`
So I set `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to `/usr/local/bin/python3.6`
When I run `virtualenvwrapper.sh` I get an error:

```
If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.6 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

so I tried to install `virtualenvwrapper` using the following command
`python3.6 -m pip install virtualenvwrapper` but it resulted with another error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

How can I fix this? Is there any workaround for installing `virtualenvwrapper` to specific python version?

More info:
`python3.6 --version` : Python 3.6.10
`python3 --version` : Python 3.9.7
I use `Ubuntu 21.10`

Comment: Can I ask for your compiler version (gcc, clang)?